# Прилагательное от "транскрипция"

Tags: словообразование

Существует ли слово "транскрипционный"? Как от слова "транскрипция" образовать прилагательное?

Comment: См.: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22транскрипционный%22&newwindow=1&client=safari&hl=ru-ru&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil0proj83zAhVt-ioKHeQyDDkQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1121&bih=1352&dpr=2

Answer (score 3):

Из «Словаря лингвистических терминов» О.С. Ахмановой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Слово "транскрипционный" зафиксировано в следующих авторитетных толковых словарях: словарь Кузнецова, словарь Ефремовой, словарь Ушакова, Малый академический словарь.

Словарные примеры: *транскрипционные правила, транскрипционные знаки, транскрипционная система*.